# Python garbage collection inside loop does not work

Tags: python, garbage-collection

I am trying to run a Python script that looks something like:

```
for directory in list_of_directories:
    data_analysis_function(directory)
```

The `data_analysis_function()` reads in about 8 GB of data from each directory and performs an analysis (which involves packages like numpy and Pandas).
The script seems to result in a pretty severe memory leak, so I tried adding in a manual call to the garbage collector at the end of each iteration of the loop:

```
import gc

for directory in list_of_directories:
    data_analysis_function(directory)
    gc.collect()
```

This does not appear to have any effect on the memory leak.

However, if I run just one or two iterations of the loop, and then call `gc.collect()`:

```
for directory in list_of_directories[:2]:
    data_analysis_function(directory)

gc.collect()
```

The garbage collection works, and reduced the memory allocated to Python to a very low value.

So, why does `gc.collect()` work outside the loop, but not inside the loop?

Comment: `directory` is just a string, not some object that is getting mutated by `data_analysis_function`, correct?

Comment: How are you diagnosing the memory leak?

Comment: In the second version, is memory actually growing larger before the GC?

Comment: What types are `directory` and `list_of_directories`?

Comment: `directory` is just a string (the name of a directory), and `list_of_directories` is a list of strings.

I am diagnosing the memory leak by watching the Memory Usage chart in the Windows Task Manager.

In the 2nd version of the script, yes, the memory usage grows before the GC.

Comment: Update: The problem has something to do with the way iPython works in Jupyter notebooks.

Comment: Update: A piece of important information that I did not include (because I didn't know it was important): 
I was running the script in a Jupyter notebook.

If I re-write the 2nd version of the script in a .py file and run it as a Python script directly, GC works as expected.

In the Jupyter notebook, the `gc.collect()` method only works if it is entered within its own cell.